# CS6 Error 1120: Access of undefined property p1RotateTimer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

all.

I'm trying to use timers within my code for ship rotation, movement, and turret rotation in a battleship-themed project that I am working on. However, Error 1120 continues to show up, despite my efforts. Any advice?

Attached is my code. The problem occurs when I do utilize TurretArray and when I do addEventListener for the timers.

```
package 
    {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import fl.transitions.*;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;
    import fl.transitions.easing.None;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.ui.*;

    [SWF(width = "600", height = "480")]

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {
        private var game:Game = new Game();

        //Sets speeds to objects
        private var bulletSpeed:int = 7;
        private var playerSpeed:Number = 0.4;
        private var playerRotateSpeed:Number = 0.1;

        //Create an array to hold multiple sprites
        private var mySpriteHolder = new Array();
        private var BulletAngle = new Array();
        private var BulletBounce = new Array();

        //Create a counter to keep track of the sprites
        private var lbCounter:int = 0;

        //Maximum number of sprites (count starts a 1 not 0)
        private var maxLB:int = 20;

        //Variable for player 1
        private var player1angle:Number = 270;
        private var keyPressed1:int = 0;
        private var keyPressed2:int = 0;
        private var keyPressed3:int = 0;
        private var keyPressed4:int = 0;
        private var p1Score:int = 0;
        private var reloaded:int = 0;
        private var k:int = 0;
        private var reloadTime:int = 10;

        private var TurretArray:Array = new Array();

        //public function loadTurrets(){
            //TurretArray = new Array();
            TurretArray[0] = mvi_PTurret1;    //Problem occurs in these 3 lines
            TurretArray[1] = mvi_PTurret2;
            TurretArray[2] = mvi_PTurret3;
        //}

        private var Turret1SpinDirection:int = 2;
        private var Turret2SpinDirection:int = 2;

        private var PTurret1angle:Number = 270;
        private var PTurret2angle:Number = 270;

        //create a new Timer

        private var p1RotateTimer:Timer = new Timer(10);
        private var p1MoveTimer:Timer = new Timer(10);
        private var PTurretRotateTimer:Timer = new Timer(10);

        //public function loadTimers(){
            //add a listener to the timer
            p1RotateTimer.addEventListener("timer",p1Rotate);   //Problem here
            p1MoveTimer.addEventListener("timer",p1Move);
            PTurretRotateTimer.addEventListener("timer",PTurretRotate);
        //}


        //Create a listener for the keypress
        //this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,PMove);
//      this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,PStop);
//      this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseCoordinate);



        public function p1Rotate(eventArgs:TimerEvent):void{

            var i:int;

            if(keyPressed1 == 68){
                mvi_PBattleship.rotation += playerRotateSpeed;
                player1angle += playerRotateSpeed;
                if(player1angle == 360){
                    player1angle = 0;
                }

                /*for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    TurretArray[i].rotation += playerRotateSpeed;
                    TurretArray[i].rotation = Math.round(TurretArray[i].rotation);
                }*/

                //txt_PlayerAngle.text = player1angle.toString();
            }
            if(keyPressed2 == 65){
                mvi_PBattleship.rotation -= playerRotateSpeed;
                player1angle -= playerRotateSpeed;
                if(player1angle == 0){
                    player1angle = 360;
                }

                /*for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    TurretArray[i].rotation -= playerRotateSpeed;
                    TurretArray[i].rotation = Math.round(TurretArray[i].rotation);
                }*/

                //txt_PlayerAngle.text = player1angle.toString();
            }


            //Keeps Turret 1 with the ship
            mvi_PTurret1.x = Math.cos(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * 32.9 + mvi_PBattleship.x;
            mvi_PTurret1.y = Math.sin(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * 32.9 + mvi_PBattleship.y;

            //Keeps Turret 2 with the ship
            mvi_PTurret2.x = Math.cos(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * 13.4 + mvi_PBattleship.x;
            mvi_PTurret2.y = Math.sin(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * 13.4 + mvi_PBattleship.y;

            //Keeps Turret 3 with the ship
            mvi_PTurret3.x = Math.cos(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * -56.5 + mvi_PBattleship.x;
            mvi_PTurret3.y = Math.sin(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * -56.5 + mvi_PBattleship.y;

        }


        public function p1Move(eventArgs:TimerEvent):void{
            /*if(p1Score > 0){
                p1Score -= pointsLost;
            }*/

            //This moves the player forward or backwards in the correct direction
            if(keyPressed3 == 87){
                x -= Math.cos(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * playerSpeed;
                y -= Math.sin(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * playerSpeed;
            }
            if(keyPressed4 == 83){
                x += Math.cos(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * playerSpeed;
                y += Math.sin(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * playerSpeed;
            }

            //This keeps the player in the center of the screen
            mvi_PBattleship.x =-x + 400;
            mvi_PBattleship.y =-y + 300;

            //txt_PBattleshipx.text = x.toString();
            //txt_PBattleshipy.text = y.toString();

            //Keeps Turret 1 with the ship
            mvi_PTurret1.x = Math.cos(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * 32.9 + mvi_PBattleship.x;
            mvi_PTurret1.y = Math.sin(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * 32.9 + mvi_PBattleship.y;

            //Keeps Turret 2 with the ship
            mvi_PTurret2.x = Math.cos(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * 13.4 + mvi_PBattleship.x;
            mvi_PTurret2.y = Math.sin(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * 13.4 + mvi_PBattleship.y;

            //Keeps Turret 3 with the ship
            mvi_PTurret3.x = Math.cos(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * -56.5 + mvi_PBattleship.x;
            mvi_PTurret3.y = Math.sin(player1angle* (Math.PI/180)) * -56.5 + mvi_PBattleship.y;

        }


        public function PMove(Evt:KeyboardEvent):void{
            //trace(Evt.keyCode);
            if(Evt.keyCode==68){
                keyPressed1 = 68;
                p1RotateTimer.start();
                }
            if(Evt.keyCode==65){
                keyPressed2 = 65;
                p1RotateTimer.start();
                }
            if(Evt.keyCode==87){
                keyPressed3 = 87;
                p1MoveTimer.start();
                }
            if(Evt.keyCode==83){
                keyPressed4 = 83;
                p1MoveTimer.start();
                }
        }


        public function PStop(Evt:KeyboardEvent):void{
            if(Evt.keyCode==87){
                keyPressed3 = 0;
                p1MoveTimer.stop();
                }
            else if(Evt.keyCode==83){
                keyPressed4 = 0;
                p1MoveTimer.stop();
                }
            else if(Evt.keyCode==68){
                keyPressed1 = 0;
                p1RotateTimer.stop();
                }
            else if(Evt.keyCode==65){
                keyPressed2 = 0;
                p1RotateTimer.stop();
                }
        }


        public function PTurretRotate(Evt:Event){

            var Mouse1x:Number;
            var Mouse1y:Number;
            var Mouse1Angle:Number;

            Mouse1x = mvi_PTurret1.x - mouseX;
            Mouse1y = mvi_PTurret1.y - mouseY;

            Mouse1Angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(Mouse1y,Mouse1x) * (180/Math.PI) + 180);

            if(Turret1SpinDirection == 0 && Mouse1Angle < 90 && PTurret1angle > 270){
                Mouse1Angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(Mouse1y,Mouse1x) * (180/Math.PI) + 180)+ 360;
            }
            else if(Turret1SpinDirection == 1 && Mouse1Angle > 270 && PTurret1angle < 90){
                Mouse1Angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(Mouse1y,Mouse1x) * (180/Math.PI) + 180)- 360;
            }

            if(PTurret1angle > 360){
                PTurret1angle = 1;
            }
            if(PTurret1angle < 0){
                PTurret1angle = 359;
            }

            if(PTurret1angle < Math.round(player1angle) - 210 || PTurret1angle > Math.round(player1angle) - 150){
            if(Mouse1Angle > PTurret1angle){
                mvi_PTurret1.rotation += 1;
                PTurret1angle += 1;
                Turret1SpinDirection = 0;
            }
            else if(Mouse1Angle < PTurret1angle){
                mvi_PTurret1.rotation -= 1;
                PTurret1angle -= 1;
                Turret1SpinDirection = 1;
            }
            }
            else{
                if(PTurret1angle == Math.round(player1angle) - 210){
                    mvi_PTurret1.rotation -= 1;
                    PTurret1angle -= 1;
                }
                else if(Math.round(player1angle) - 210 < 0){
                    if(PTurret1angle + 90 == Math.round(player1angle) - 210 + 90){
                        mvi_PTurret1.rotation -= 1;
                        PTurret1angle -= 1;
                    }
                }
                if(PTurret1angle == Math.round(player1angle) - 150){
                    mvi_PTurret1.rotation += 1;
                    PTurret1angle += 1;
                }
            }



            var Mouse2x:Number;
            var Mouse2y:Number;
            var Mouse2Angle:Number;

            Mouse2x = mvi_PTurret2.x - mouseX;
            Mouse2y = mvi_PTurret2.y - mouseY;

            Mouse2Angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(Mouse2y,Mouse2x) * (180/Math.PI) + 180);

            if(Turret2SpinDirection == 0 && Mouse2Angle < 90 && PTurret2angle > 270){
                Mouse2Angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(Mouse2y,Mouse2x) * (180/Math.PI) + 180)+ 360;
            }
            else if(Turret2SpinDirection == 1 && Mouse2Angle > 270 && PTurret2angle < 90){
                Mouse2Angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(Mouse2y,Mouse2x) * (180/Math.PI) + 180)- 360;
            }

            if(PTurret2angle > 360){
                PTurret2angle = 1;
            }
            if(PTurret2angle < 0){
                PTurret2angle = 359;
            }


            if(Mouse2Angle > PTurret2angle){
                mvi_PTurret2.rotation += 1;
                PTurret2angle += 1;
                Turret2SpinDirection = 0;
            }
            else if(Mouse2Angle < PTurret2angle){
                mvi_PTurret2.rotation -= 1;
                PTurret2angle -= 1;
                Turret2SpinDirection = 1;
            }

            //txt_Turret1Angle.text = Mouse1Angle.toString();
            //txt_PTurret.text = PTurret1angle.toString();
        }


        public function mouseCoordinate(Evt:Event){
            //txt_X.text = mouseX.toString();
            //txt_Y.text = mouseY.toString();
            PTurretRotateTimer.start();
        }



        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
            stage.frameRate = 30;

            addChild(game);
        }

        private function mouseMove(e :MouseEvent) :void {
            Game.mouse.x = e.stageX;
            Game.mouse.y = e.stageY;
        }

        private function enterFrame(e :Event) :void {
            game.update();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, uhm, **how** do you expect the `addEventListener` to work out of any function?! Why you've commented `loadTimers`?!

Comment: @AndreyPopov: Hi again and thanks for the response! So, I removed the commenting of loadTimers like you said. Just for good measure, I did the same for loadTurrets. Now, while all errors appear to have vanished, I seem to be unable to control my ship in any way, even though clear actions for it are outlined in the functions created from addEventListener. Any advice?

Comment: I asked **why** you've removed the function?! The listener **must** be inside a function in order to work!

Comment: @AndreyPopov: That was my mistake, I wasn't thinking when I did that. I think I meant to comment out a different line.